# Support for redirected drives in OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

We're in the process of trying to get one of our old .NET 3.5 Windows Forms applications to work on a server, where people will be able to access it via Remote Desktop.

We have hit a snag with regards to accessing file on the user's local machine.  The application needs to be able to export and import files to the user's computer.  We've been using the standard .NET OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog components to facilitate this hitherto.  Unfortunately, even though users are sharing their local drive via drive redirection on the Remote Desktop clent AND users can access file/folders using Windows Explorer remotely... it seems the OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog components do not allow access to these shared drives.

Every time we try to browse to a user's drive inside the remote session, the error "The Folder [folder name] can't be used. Please choose another folder." (FolderBrowserDialog) or literally nothing happens inside the OpenFileDialog when you choose the shared drive.

Does anyone know of a way around this?  Or does anyone know of a third party component / solution that may help?

We're faced with the prospect of having users drag and drop files onto the desktop using Windows Explorer remotely as a way of proxying the files back n forth.

Comment: Seems strange, I can access the folderbrowser on remote. But I have an admin account. Try to start the application as administrator, that might work.

Comment: Hi there, yeah, I'm running it as Admin, I can access the folder browser and browse local folders, but I cannot access or browse to folders on the drive redirection / TS client drive.

Comment: I have written a small test application and installed it on one of our servers, connected to it via RDP with drive redirection enabled. I was able to browse all drives/folders and also browse folders/files using the dialogs. I had a button for selecting a file using the OpenFileDialog and I could succesfully select a file on any of my local drives. Another button uses the path from the OpenFileDialog to open this file in Notepad and I could edit + save it.

Comment: FYI: I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, Windows Server 2008 64-bit and the application was targeted at the .NET Framework 4.0. I will try again with 3.5. EDIT: Same result with Framework 3.5

Comment: OK, I have discovered the reason is because I have to run the application as administrator.  Right click "Run as administrator".

Comment: @Boomerangertanger, Put this as the answer so this can get closed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because I had to run the application as administrator. Right click "Run as administrator".  This for some reason prevents drive redirection from working.